# Making certain columns in Devexpress Gridview editable only when adding new row

Tags: vb.net, gridview, devexpress

I have a Gridview in Devexpress.  I want the first 3 columns
to be editable when I'm adding information to a new row but I want them
to be read-only when I'm updating a row.

Now I'm able to do this when I have a popup window do add info but I want to be able add/modify information directly in the GridView.  [image]

How do I got about this? (See pic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this :

```
Private Sub GridView1_ShowingEditor(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles GridView1.ShowingEditor
    Dim ListOfColumnEditOnlyInAdd() As String = {"ColumnName1", "ColumnName2", "ColumnName3"}
    if not gridView1.IsNewItemRow(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle) And ListOfColumnEditOnlyInAdd.Contains(gridView1.FocusedColumn.FieldName) then
        e.Cancel = true
    end if
End Sub
```